# Number of parameters that can be passed to a web service?

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I am in the brainstorming phase of designing an API.

I was just wondering if I have to worry about the number of parameters or the number of characters that I will be passing to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GET method you're limited to 2048 characters reliably (at least Internet Explorer has this limit).

However, [RFC 2616, Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) doesn't specify a size limit for URL's.

There is no limit for POST method.